# Can't connect to remote hdfs using spring hadoop

Tags: spring, hadoop, hdfs

I'm just starting in Hadoop and I'm trying to read from remote hdfs (remote hdfs in a docker container, accessible from localhost:32783) trough Spring Hadoop but I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.hadoop.HadoopException: 
Cannot list resources Failed on local exception: 
java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "user/127.0.1.1";    
destination host is: "localhost":32783;
```

I'm triying to read the file using the following code:

```
    HdfsClient hdfsClient = new HdfsClient();

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://localhost:32783");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    SimplerFileSystem sFs = new SimplerFileSystem(fs);
    hdfsClient.setsFs(sFs);

    String filePath = "/tmp/tmpTestReadTest.txt";
    String output = hdfsClient.readFile(filePath);
```

What hdfsClient.readFile(filePath) does is the following:

```
public class HdfsClient {

        private SimplerFileSystem sFs;

        public String readFile(String filePath) throws IOException {

            FSDataInputStream inputStream = this.sFs.open(filePath);
            output =  getStringFromInputStream(inputStream.getWrappedStream());
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return output;
}
```

Any guess why I can't read from the remote hdfs? Removing the  conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://localhost:32783"); I can read, but just from local filepath.

I understand that the "hdfs://localhost:32783" is correct because changing it by a random uri gives Connection refused error

There migh be something wrong into my hadoop configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: After some work I've achieved to solve this. The problem was about the docker image, so after downloading and compiling it again the hdfs conexion worked fine!
Extra info: I've used the following hadoop docker img: https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/

Comment: what was problem with image? I am trying to connect my java application to hadoop in docker and I get same error? what is the fix you made?

Comment: @brainstorm I don't remember too much about this error now, but I think removing the docker image, downloading it again and recompailing it solved my problem last time. Hope it helps.